# If/else Python 3: Else statement not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Currently working on my first program and my Else statement isn't working in the following code:

```
info = input("<Y/N>")

if (info == "Y" or "y"):
   print("Calculating...")

else:
   raise SystemExit
```

The program just continues to

> print("Calculating...")

even if the input isn't **`"Y"`** or **`"y"`**

Comment: because ``"y"`` is always ``True``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (info == "Y" or "y"):
```

is equivalent to saying

```
if ((info == "Y") or ("y"))
```

Since `y` is not zero, null, or equivalent, it evaluates to true.
The either of the following will do:

```
if (info == "Y" or info == "y")
if (info in ("y", "Y"))
if (info.lower() == "y")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write something like this:

```py
info = input("<Y/N>")

if (info == "Y" or info == "y"):
   print ("Calculating...")

else:
   raise SystemExit
```

In your statement:

```py
info == "Y" or info == "y"
```

`"y"` is always `True`

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the `or` operator is treating the left and right side as boolean (True and False) statements. What it's looking to see on the left side is `info == "Y"` which might be true or false depending on the input. On the right side it's seeing `"y"` and checking if `"y"` is true. In python non-empty strings count as true when evaluated as booleans. To fix this here are two ways to check.

1. `if info == "Y" or info == "y":`
2. `if info in ["y", "Y"]:`

Answer (score 0):

Let me just add this to the above answers: a more pythonic way of checking

`if (info == 'Y' or info == 'y')`

is done by

`if info.lower() == 'y'`.

Of course, `info` needs to be a string.